# Quick question about $\diamondsuit_\kappa$

Tags: set-theory, infinitary-combinatorics

I've run into the claim that $\diamondsuit_\kappa$ is equivalent to the (weaker looking) principle $\diamondsuit_\kappa^*$: That there's a sequence of $X_\alpha$ ($\alpha<\kappa$) with $X_\alpha\subseteq\mathcal{P}(\alpha)$, $|X_\alpha|\leq\alpha$, and for any $X\subseteq\kappa$, the set $\{\alpha<\kappa\mid X\cap\alpha\in X_\alpha\}$ is stationary in kappa.

It's pretty obvious why $\diamondsuit_\kappa$ would imply $\diamondsuit_\kappa^*$. But I can't see why the other direction should hold. Anyone have a quick answer to this question?

Comment: In the book Set Theory: An Introduction To Independence Proofs, by Kenneth Kunen, there is a proof for the case $k=\omega_1$ in the first edition, pages 85-86 :Chapter II, Theorem 7.14 . He uses $\diamond^-$  for $\diamond^*.$  I wouldn't call it "quick."